# Improve Copy Editor badge description

Tags: feature-request, badges, edit-badges

The description of the [Copy Editor badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor) currently says:

> Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits).

The term 'tag edit' is a bit ambiguous; what is meant here are edits to questions where only tags are changed ('retaggings'). If you change both the body (or the title) and the tags of a question, it does count towards the Copy Editor badge. Also, edits of tag wikis and tag excerpts count. For details and sources, see the [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/295232).

Can we improve the wording? Something like

> Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and edits that only change tags).

which is still concise but unambiguous.

Comment: How about "excluding own or deleted posts and tag-only edits"?

Comment: That would do the job as well.